# Should I scrape off firmly-attached, cracked exterior paint before repainting?

Tags: painting, exterior

When preparing to paint the exterior, there are some shingles that appear to show cracks but the paint seems to be firm. Should I still scrape it off?

Answer (score 1):

If you run a scraper across it and it doesn't come off then it is likely OK to leave it. You should still sand it well and prime before painting.

For aesthetics I would probably sand it smooth, it will be visible under the new paint.